# Granting a role to user (Postgres + Npgsql + Dapper) results to "syntax error at or near "$1""

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I'm trying to issue a command to PostgreSQL with Dapper+Npgsql:

```
using (var dbConn = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionStringWithDatabaseName))
{
    dbConn.Open();
    dbConn.Execute("GRANT pg_read_all_data TO @user", new { @user = username }, commandTimeout: _sqlCommandTimeout);
}
```

The variable `username` is set as string `agentuser` and `_sqlCommandTimeout` as int `240`.
This query works when fired off from HeidiSQL.

I can do other queries and stuff successfully, but this one fails:

```
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42601
    MessageText: syntax error at or near "$1"
    Position: 29
    File: scan.l
    Line: 1176
    Routine: scanner_yyerror
```

What am I doing wrong here?

My PostgreSQL version is 14.1, Dapper is 2.0.35, Npgsql 4.1.10 and the project targets .NET Framework 4.7.1.

Comment: Never done what you're trying to do but I'd say it looks like the user name is not parameterizable. All the examples I see are like `GRANT x ON y TO z` not `GRANT x ON y TO 'z'` so I would assume that the username is more like an identifier than a variable. ie it doesn't work for similar reasons as you cannot do `SELECT * FROM @tablename`

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard for response. Is there a workaround for this, that could still parameterize the username?

Comment: Thanks @JGH; blame the IPhone's font, my eyes and everything in between!

Comment: I think it might work to do `execute format('GRANT pg_read_all_data TO %I', @user)` but I'm not in a position to test it.. PG's format function, when told `%I` will apparently treat it as an SQL identifier and quote as necessary. You could also form the string yourself after checking that it's a valid username, or if your usernames have some rule like "only a-z and underscores allowed" then a regex to remove any non compliant characters would also go some way towards mitigating injection risk

Comment: If forming yourself after checking eg `SELECT usename FROM pg_catalog.pg_user` verify that usernames cannot be registered that contain SQL, because there aint much point putting the check in if there's a way to sneak SQL into the username such that it will be pulled from the DB, assumed to be safe "because it's in the DB" and concatted into a command

Answer (score -1):

PostgresSQL doesn't use `@` for parameters, it uses `:`. So, change your code to:

```cs
using (var dbConn = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionStringWithDatabaseName))
{
    dbConn.Open();
    dbConn.Execute("GRANT pg_read_all_data TO :user", new { user = username }, commandTimeout: _sqlCommandTimeout);
}
```

I have no idea, if it works with user, though.

Comment: That's not true, `@` works perfectly fine for parameter placeholders, just as well as `:`. In fact, the native PostgreSQL parameter placeholder is $, and is positional, not named ($1, $2) - Npgsql parses and replaces the placeholders before it sends queries to PostgreSQL.

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware that NpgSql intervened. But it's clear form the documentation here: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html